# AngularJS Infinite Scroll Issue

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I code an infinite scrolled DIV for an AngularJS bootstrap app, as shown in the following example.

[When Scrolled Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvuyka/QSwN2/)

```
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
        }
    });
};
```

});

Data is loaded but the scroll of the DIV goes to bottom and to see the data loaded you need to scroll up again. How do I fix this?

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wR1p.png)

Comment: How are you implementing this? Can I see the view?

Comment: I add an image, I have a panel that work with ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Does the div with ng-repeat have `id="fixed"`, along with the following CSS?

```
#fixed {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes the div have both CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the data I received replace all the array, I code using push into the ng-repeat array.

```
array.push (tempArray[i])
```